# How to reference branch name in a git commit -a -m "message" message?

Tags: git

How to reference branch name in a message of a git commit -a -m? Something like:

```
git commit -a -m "$branchName done"
```

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to track whether feature branches are done. Why not do that by the merge commit messages?

Comment: @NilsWerner I use bitbucket and it seems to not display merge messages next to commits. So commit descriptions are not informative without adding branch name to commit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouter de Kort's powershell answer ported to bash would be:

```
git commit -m "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) done"
```

Answer (score 4):

`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` will give you the current branch name. You do have to make sure that there is at least one commit in the branch otherwise this won't work. Depending on your OS/shell you can then use some string concatenation to create your commit message.

This is a PowerShell sample:

```
$branchName = git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
git commit -m "Initial commit on branch $branchName"
```

Comment: What would be the bash equivalent?

Comment: git commit -m "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) done" as @Nils Werner shows

Answer (score 1):

One of the way:

```
git commit -am "$(git branch | awk '/\*/ { print $2; }') done"
```